# Replace attribute name in SQL Server XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath, xquery-sql

I have a table `MyTable` with a xml column `MyXmlField` like this :

```
    <Root>
      <Node Type="type1" position="0"/>
      <Node Type="type2" position="2"/>
      <Node Type="type3" position="4"/>
      <Node Type="type4" position="2"/>
      <Node Type="type5" position="4"/>
      <Node Type="type6" position="0"/>
    </Root>
```

The `Type` attribute has a value which can be any value between those :

```
    type1, type2, type3, type4, type5, type6.
```

The position attribute has a value which can be any integer.

What I would like to do with a XQuery is to update attribute `Type` of every element `Node` as the following :

- change the name from `Type` to `Identifier`

So finally, I would like to have this :

```
    <Root>
      <Node Identifier="type1" position="0"/>
      <Node Identifier="type2" position="2"/>
      <Node Identifier="type3" position="4"/>
      <Node Identifier="type4" position="2"/>
      <Node Identifier="type5" position="4"/>
      <Node Identifier="type6" position="0"/>
    </Root>
```

I am a beginner with XQuery, and I do not see how to do it properly other than transforming everything into `varchar` and doing a replace. Right now, I
am only able to query each value with 6 hardcoded requests like this :

```
    /Root/Node[@Type=type1)]/text())[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [next approach](http://rextester.com/WDA96353), but you need to consider possible performance problems:

```
with
  MyTable as(
    select cast(x as xml) MyXmlField
    from(values('
<Root>
  <Node Type="type1" position="0"/>
  <Node Type="type2" position="2"/>
  <Node Type="type3" position="4"/>
  <Node Type="type4" position="2"/>
  <Node Type="type5" position="4"/>
  <Node Type="type6" position="0"/>
</Root>
'),('
<Root id="170">
  <Node Type="type1" position="0"/>
  <Node Type="type2" position="2"/>
  <Node Type="type3" position="4"/>
  <Node Type="type4" position="2"/>
  <Node Type="type5" position="4"/>
  <Node Type="type6" position="0"/>
  <foo/>
  <foo bar="42">170</foo>
</Root>
'))t(x)
  )
select MyXmlField.query('
<Root>
  {/Root/@*}
  {
    for $elem in /Root/*
      return
        if(local-name($elem) = "Node")
        then
          <Node>
          {
            for $attr in $elem/@*
              return
                if(local-name($attr) = "Type")
                then attribute Identifier {$attr}
                else $attr
          }
          {$elem/node()}
          </Node>
        else $elem
  }
</Root>
')
from MyTable
```